# Overwrite console.command_loader in Symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony

Overwriting a Symfony Service is pretty straight forward and works for other services.
But I'm unable to overwrite the console.command_loader. I tested it in 5.4 as well as in 6.3.

These lines I added to the services.yml:

```
console.command_loader:
    class: App\Service\Test
```

And after that, debug:container still points to the Original class:

```
php bin/console debug:container console.command_loader

Information for Service "console.command_loader"
================================================

 Loads commands from a PSR-11 container.

 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Service ID       console.command_loader
  Class            Symfony\Component\Console\CommandLoader\ContainerCommandLoader
  Tags             container.no_preload
  Public           yes
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        no
  Autoconfigured   no
  Usages           none
 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

My goal is to disable some symfony commands for production, and I think the easiest way is to do it while overwriting console.command_loader.

If you know any better solution on how to hide i.e. doctrine:schema:drop and many others on production, I'm happy to hear your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why it can't be overwritten is this class:

```
vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/DependencyInjection/AddConsoleCommandPass.php

$container
        ->register($this->commandLoaderServiceId, ContainerCommandLoader::class)
        ->setPublic(true)
        ->addTag($this->noPreloadTag)
        ->setArguments([ServiceLocatorTagPass::register($container, $lazyCommandRefs), $lazyCommandMap]);
```